# Does SQL Server 2016 Evaluation version have a 10GB size limit?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed a new server and also installed SQL Server 2016 Evaluation version and SQL Server Management Studio 17.1 with it.

I'm trying to restore a database in this supposed 'test environment' to test a few procedures before pushing to production.

My database is about 212gb large. While I was trying to restore the database to this server, I got an error message:

> Msg 1827, Level 16, State 4, Line 5
>   CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I thought the Evaluation version was free to use for 180 days. It has been only about 30 or so days.

I thought the 10GB limit was only for SQL Server Express edition.

I checked the Control Panel to confirm that I indeed have 2016 Evaluation version and not the Express edition.

Comment: When you connect to the database in management studio, and then select properties from the context menu, what value is in the "product" box?

Comment: Damn... It says Express. But I didn't even see it in the Control Panel Programs and I'm not even sure how to uninstall it.... Is there a way to make Mgmnt Studio connect to the 2016 Evaluation version?

Comment: Check version with `SELECT @@VERSION`; There is step in installation where you choose edition, perhaps you have made mistake there; Evaluation edition should have features like Enterprise and Developer.

Comment: Select @@VERSION result is........ Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)   Oct 19 2012 13:38:57   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor) ............   How do I uninstall this?

Comment: You can uninstall SQL Server from Control Panel -> Programs -> right click... like any other program.... But, you can also try to upgrade edition -> run SQL Server setup again and choose Maintenance -> Edition upgrade

Comment: In Control Panel, while trying to uninstall SQL Server, I see 4 instances. 3 od Evaluation Edition and 1 of Developer edition. None of Express edition. Why is my Management studio still using the Express edition?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've actually installed the Express version, or that your the licensing configuration has somehow gotten out of wack.

I don't believe you can manually convert from Express to the Evaluation version. You'll probably need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. So frustrating. Would've been so much easier to just reinstall the whole operating system. But then reinstalling the Virtual Machine again will be such a pain.